# Streamlit application reloads every 30secs when deployed on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, streamlit

Hi I have deployed a streamlit application which acts as a UI for downloading data from our platform. After deploying on kubernetes I observe that application keeps reloading after every 30 seconds, which is very annoying.
If I access the app by port forwarding the service it works ok but somehow using via nginx, it has the above mentioned problem.

Has anyone faced this issue ?

I was looking into the streamlit forum and saw same issue like mine but there is no clear solution.

[Streamlit reruns all 30 seconds](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-reruns-all-30-seconds/7201)

I do see a websocket time of ~30s in developer tool under network section in browser.

[image]

My k8s manifest file is as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: streamlit-deployment
  labels:
    app: streamlit
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: streamlit
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: streamlit
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: streamlit
          image: <image>:<tag>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8501
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8501
              scheme: HTTP
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8501
              scheme: HTTP
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 745Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data           
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data            
            
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: streamlit
  name: streamlit-service
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32640
    port: 8501
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8501
  selector:
    app: streamlit
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp

  labels: 
    app: streamlit
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /webapp(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: streamlit-service
            port:
              number: 8501
```

`

I tried to add following annotation in nginx definition but it didnt work
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining: "true"     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining-timeout: "3000"`

Also I looked into the source code and was wondering if its because of tornado settings in
lib/streamlit/web/server/server.py which has web socket ping timeout set as 30 seconds.
`"websocket_ping_timeout": 30,`
I tried to set this to a higher value and create a new image for my deployment, but unfortunately it didnt help.

I'd really appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we found out that issue was due to the default time out of the GCP load balancer, which was causing the web socket connection to re-initialize every 30 secs. All we needed to do was change the time out in the backend configuration of the load balancer. I hope it helps.